# Cannot get the facebook's user's timeline with api 2.5

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the facebook's user's timeline in my Android app.
Here my code :

```
mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_about_me", "user_friends", "user_likes",
            "user_photos", "user_relationships", "user_posts",
            "user_status"));

    // If using in a fragment
    mLoginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    mLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            for (String permission : loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Granted Permission:" + permission);
            }

            getUserFeed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
```

And after the login, I launch this :

```
private void getUserFeed() {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putInt("limit", 25);
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,link,full_picture,message,story,picture,type,place,from,to");
    params.putBoolean("summary", true);

    /* make the API call */
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/home",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        final JSONArray data = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        //currentJson = response.getJSONObject();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

I have this respond code from Facebook :

```
Requires extended permission: read_stream
```

I know this permission is depreceted, I'm using the latest API 2.5.

Do you know if we can continue to get the user's timeline now, if I replace the "/me/home" by "/me/feed" it's ok, but I just get my posts, not my entire timeline.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if we can continue to get the user's timeline now,

No, you can’t.

> if I replace the "/me/home" by "/me/feed" it's ok, but I just get my posts, not my entire timeline.

`/me/home` was deprecated together with the permission.

`/me/feed` is what you can get now, and that’s it.

Which posts you can expect to see is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#readperms

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not good for me, it was the base of my future application :p